# Itinerating for each position to compare with a number AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here is what i want to, i have a kind of calculator, that calculator has two array list (number1 and number2) and other array with the sum of two list (resultAll), to verify the result i need to click a number i'm using `ng-click` with a function to get the data from a keyboard numeric, but it's comparing each number with all the array sum, how can i compare for each one?

```
            $scope.number1 = [];
            $scope.number2 = [];
            $scope.result = 0;
            $scope.numbto = [];
            $scope.resultAll = [];
            $scope.posi = [];

            $scope.showing = false;
            /** crea inputs **/
    $scope.getTimes = function(n){
         return new Array(n);
    };
            /* show / hide keyboard numbers */

            $scope.showHide = function(){
                $scope.showing = $scope.showin ? false : true;
            }

        for (var i = 0; i <= 6; i++){
                $scope.number1[i] = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
                $scope.number2[i] = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);

                $scope.resultAll.push($scope.number1[i] + $scope.number2[i])
            }
            console.log($scope.resultAll)

            $scope.numberButtonClicked = function(numb){
                $scope.numbto.push(numb)
                    console.log("result : "+$scope.numbto)
                    //debugger
                    angular.forEach($scope.resultAll, function(value1, key1){
                        console.log("valor1 :"+value1)
                        angular.forEach($scope.numbto, function(value2){
                            console.log("valor2 :"+value2)
                            //debugger
                            if(value1 === value2){
                                console.log("ok")
                            }else{
                                console.log("no")
                            }
                            return 0;

                                });
                            });
                        }
                 }
```

and here is html

```
    <div ng-app="myApp">
 <div ng-controller="HardCtrl">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col"></div>
      <div class="col" ng-repeat="num in number1 | limitTo:7 track by $index">
        <span>{{num}}</span>
      </div>
    </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">+</div>
        <div class="col" ng-repeat="num in number2 | limitTo:7 track by $index">
          <span>{{num}}</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col"></div>

    <div class="col"  ng-repeat="x in getTimes(7) track by $index" >
        <input type="number" ng-click="showHide()" ng-model="numbto[$index]"  style="width:50px;margin-left:35px;border:1px solid black;">
    </div>

    </div>

    <div class="contenedor" style="margin-top:50px;" ng-show="showing">

        <div class="section group">
            <div ng-click="numberButtonClicked(9)" class="col c1of4">9</div>
            <div ng-click="numberButtonClicked(8)" class="col c1of4">8</div>
            <div ng-click="numberButtonClicked(7)" class="col c1of4">7</div>

        </div>
        <div class="section group"> <!-- Display the 2nd number row -->
            <div ng-click="numberButtonClicked(6)" class="col c1of4">6</div>
            <div ng-click="numberButtonClicked(5)" class="col c1of4">5</div>
            <div ng-click="numberButtonClicked(4)" class="col c1of4">4</div>

        </div>
        <div class="section group"> <!-- Display the 3rd number row -->
            <div ng-click="numberButtonClicked(3)" class="col c1of4">3</div>
            <div ng-click="numberButtonClicked(2)" class="col c1of4">2</div>
            <div ng-click="numberButtonClicked(1)" class="col c1of4">1</div>
        </div>
    <div class="section group"> <!-- Display the 3rd number row -->
      <div ng-click="numberButtonClicked(0)" class="col c1of4">0</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

example: when i sum two numbers of the two arrays = 5 (for example number1 = 3 + number2 = 2) and when i click at the input it's showing a keyboard and i click 5 it's correct can continue with the next one
https://jsfiddle.net/yfkjmren/7/

Comment: Please include the relevant code in the question itself. Questions should be self contained and we shouldn't have to go off site to review your issue. Demos are then used to support what actually exists in the question

Comment: Not really clear what the demo is supposed to do either

Comment: for example when i sum two numbers of the two arrays it's  5 (for example numb1 = 3 + number2 = 2) and when i click at the input it's showing a keyboard and i click 5 if it's ok i can continue

Comment: Hum...What ? What are you trying to do ? What is your problem ?

Comment: i'm trying to verify each result with the number i clicked,  i can test the first result but no the others because the loop is comparing this number i clicked with the others